# how to use variable of one module in other in express node js

Tags: node.js, express

I have one file where I have written following code:

```
    var db_abc= express();
    var mysql = require('mysql')

        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'abc_db'
        })

        connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('You are now connected...')

    })

module.exports = db_abc;
```

Now I want to use connection in other file to write queries:

```
var db_abc = require('../db_abc')

db_abc.connection.query('SELECT tid, type, status, ' +
    'created, modified, jdp_response FROM jdp_tb_trade ' +
    'WHERE status="TRADE_FINISHED" AND type = "tmall_i18n" ' +
    //'AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ' + start + ' MINUTES) <= modified' +
    // 'AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL ' + end + ' MINUTES) >= modified' +
    'ORDER BY modified',
    function (err, results) {
        if (!err)
            console.log('The solution is: ', results);
        else
            console.log('Error while performing Query.');

    });
```

If I write above query in same file where I have define connection then it successfully executes. but when I use db_abc module and import it and use connection variable to call query then it says query is not define.

Any suggestion on how to use variables of other module in express would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting `db_abc` which is an `express` application. Express does not have a `connection` variable.

I think that you wanted to do something like

```
var db_abc= express();
var mysql = require('mysql')

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'abc_db'
})

connection.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('You are now connected...')
})

module.exports = {
  connection, // Export connection here
};
```

And then you can use it like this

```
var db_abc = require('../db_abc')
db_abc.connection...
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me try this solution.

Comment: When I write this part : module.exports = {
  connection, // Export connection here
}; it gives me error shorthand property name is not supported by current javascript function.

Comment: It seems that you are using an old version of nodejs, so you need to write `module.exports = {
  connection: connection
};` instead